# How do i style 'item' pages, depending on their tag in blogger?

Tags: html, blogger

I have been playing around with blogger for some time. the problem i have is that i need to give post 'item' pages a custom style, if they have a certain tag.

This is how it needs to work.

This is the default home page of the blog:
etreeblog.blogspot. co .uk

But twhis page for the shop 'LeaValleyWines' is custom to it's shop theme.
http://etreeblog.blogspot.co.uk/search/label/LeaValleyWines

What i need is a post like this one, with the label 'LeaValleyWines', to have the same style as the LeaValleyWines page.
http://etreeblog.blogspot.co.uk/2015/01/gift-ideas-from-leavalleywines.html

This will continue for all the pages.

To do list:
-If the post has no tag it must take the default theme.
-I need to be able to add as many tags, with styles, as possible.
-Each tag has a custom theme and needs to edit the whole page, not just the post.

Things that may help:
-Each post will 'always', unless by mistake, have a label. 
-Each post has only ONE label at a time. (to sort it into the store)

If you have any ideas or suggestions on how to do this, please answer.

I know about blogger IF statements, but i dont know how to check an 'item' page for a tag, only how to check the post it's self.

Thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
 <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
  <b:if cond='data:label.name == &quot;YOUR FIRST LABEL NAME&quot;'>
    <style>
    background-color:#FFF;
    </style>
  </b:if>
  <b:if cond='data:label.name == &quot;YOUR SECOND LABEL NAME&quot;'>
    <style>
    background-color:#000;
    </style>
  </b:if>
 </b:loop>
</b:if>
```

This will work but it has to be placed anywhere within `<b:includable id='post' var='post'>` for it to work. `<style>` should be placed in the `<head>` but the `<b:loop` for labels will not work in the head so because of blogger's limitations you'll be forced to do it a little sloppy but it will work. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I wrote something similar to this during my first attempts, however I did not have knowledge of the having to be within the posts. I have just implemented the code and changed it to my specifications and it works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I am no big script writer, but I suppose you could check the tag container for a string and then maybe attach another stylesheet to the head-tag, that will do the custom style. If it is only CSS that you want to change.
Or maybe add a specific class to the body if the script finds the specific string in the tags. That might be easier than attaching another stylesheet.